# How to set universe name and name spaces in yugabyte-db?

Tags: yugabytedb

I searched to set universe name and name spaces in yugabyte-db.
but, couldn't manage.

Please guide me in setting universe name and name spaces in yugabyte-db.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your YB master like this:

```
./bin/yb-master --flagfile /db/master.conf >& /db/yb-master.out &
```

and put the following data into your `/db/master.conf`:

```
--placement_zone=your-zone
--placement_region=your-region
--placement_cloud=your-cloud
```

The corresponding reference is located here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#geo-distribution-options

Cheers